# open the maps app with coordinates in iOS5

Tags: ios5, ios6, maps, coordinates

In my app there is a contact us view that will have a button to open the company's address. So My code works fine in iOS6 and I know it should be different for iOS 5 but couldn't find the proper way to do it.
Here is my code:

```
// Check for iOS 6
BOOL iOS6 = NO;

Class mapItemClass = [MKMapItem class];
if (mapItemClass && [mapItemClass respondsToSelector:@selector(openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:)])
    iOS6 = YES;

switch (buttonIndex) {
    case 0:

        if (iOS6) 
        {
         // Create an MKMapItem to pass to the Maps app
         CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate =
         CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(26.375561, 50.170305);
         MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate
         addressDictionary:nil];
         MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
         [mapItem setName:@"Industrial Projects Technologies"];
         // Pass the map item to the Maps app
         [mapItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:nil];
         }

        else
        {
            // Use the iOS 5 method
        }
        break;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code for iOS5 for showing source to destination route

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=%@,%@&saddr=%@,%@",latitudeOfDestinationLocation,longitudeOfDestinationLocation,latitudeOfSourceLocation,longitudeOfSourceLocation]]];
```

To show particular point in map

```
maps.google.com/?q=latitude,longitude
```

Example: `maps.google.com/?q=26.375561,50.170305`

You can also refer to [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html).

Comment: Yes, I saw this in the documentation but I don't have a source location and a destination location. I'm just trying to display a place mark for one location only.

Comment: I'll try it. I don't have an iOS 5 iPhone to verify it works. But could you please edit the question accordingly.